# Active model serialization not working with api versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I have api with version system.

My controller

```
    module Api;module V1
        class PlansController < ApplicationController        
          def show
            @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
            render json: @plan
          end 
        end
    end;end
```

I have folder serializers/api/v1 where i have plan_serializer.rb

```
module Api;module V1
    class PlanSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :name, :amount, :days
    end
end;end
```

But its not serializing json response automatically. 
Please tell me what wrong am I doing ?

I also tried adding

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization
```

but still its not working.

If I am doing

```
render json: @plan, serializer: V1::PlanSerializer
```

then it is working but I want it to work without adding serializer in every render.

Please tell me solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may work if you override `render`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization
  DEFAULT_SERIALIZER= V1::PlanSerializer

  def render options, &block
    options[:serializer]= DEFAULT_SERIALIZER unless options[:serializer]
    super options, &block
  end

end
```

Comment: According to activemodel 0.10 doc- "When serializing a model inside a namespace, such as Api::V1::Post, ActiveModelSerializers will expect the corresponding serializer to be inside the same namespace (namely Api::V1::PostSerializer).
"

Comment: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md
but its not working :(